# How to test a view element in Angular with Karma and Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm starting out with Karma and Jasmine and I have a problem.

Html:

```
<input id="dateTimePicker" ng-change="vm.enableConfirm = vm.matchDate == null" ng-click="vm.openCalendar($event, prop)" type="text" datetime-picker="dd MM yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="vm.matchDate" is-open="vm.isOpen" />
```

I want to test if the calendar opens when the ng-click is performed.

Controller code:

```
vm.openCalendar = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  vm.isOpen = true;
};
```

Spec.js:

```
...
it('Check if openCalendar opens the calendar', function () {
      angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#dateTimePicker')).triggerHandler('click');
      controller.openCalendar();
      //nothing yet
    });
...
```

I get the error that openCalendar doesn't gets the event parameter. How can I properly test this controller function?

Answer (score 0):

It is all the same for any kind of function that expects mocked arguments, not just event handler.

In one spec `controller.openCalendar` is tested:

```
var e = {
  preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy(),
  stopPropagation: jasmine.createSpy()
};

controller.openCalendar(e);

expect(e.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(e.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(controller.isOpen).toBe(true);
```

In another spec the view is tested with stubbed `controller.openCalendar`:

```
spyOn(controller, 'openCalendar');
element.click();
expect(controller.openCalendar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Object), ...);
```

Where `element` is `input` element that was compiled with `$compile`. In tests DOM elements are detached and aren't reachable for `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: and how does this make sure that the calendar is opened in the view?

Comment: It shouldn't. Unit tests should be performed in isolation. I've updated the answer to make it more clear. The entire behaviour may be tested in Protractor e2e test, but in unit tests (Karma) we test them separately, line by line.